# netcoreapp2.0 with netstandard2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a project(x) that targets the NetStandard.Library 2.0 and a console app that targets netcoreapp2.0.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library" Version="2.0.0-beta-25021-01" />
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.0.0-beta-001588-00" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\x.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Project X:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="NETStandard.Library" Version="2.0.0-beta-25017-01" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When I compile the console application I get the Error:

Project x is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0) / win-x86. Project x supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

I have installed: Microsoft net core 2.0.0 runtime located here: https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup but it still doesnt build.

*edited following advice from below:
I have installed the Alpha SDK located here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/tree/master#installers-and-binaries and I still get the same error.

[image]

The interesting thing is that there is a nuget package reference for Microsoft.NETCore.App which I cannot remove: 
[image]

Comment: It is not yet even previewed. Don't attempt unless you are ready to learn from the code and its GitHub repos.

Comment: ..\x.csproj ... Is not the x project containing all source from your web project?

Comment: @CodeJunkie and that's why I left a comment. When something is being cooked, there is no concrete answer.

Comment: Thomas, x.csproj is a class library referenced by my web project. That is the full file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET Core 2.0 will require the .NET Core 2.0 SDK. Download links to nightlies are available here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/tree/master#installers-and-binaries

Heads up: nightly builds of this are very unstable right now. As of February 2017, .NET Core 2.0 has no public release. Checkout https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/dogfooding.md for instructions on using nightlies.

Comment: I installed the v 2.0.0 alpha SDK and uninstalled all other versions but still see the same error: 
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Common.targets(63,5): error : Project 'D:\x.csproj' targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.

Comment: For now, you can only build from command line with dotnet.exe. VS does not use dotnet.exe to compile. The 2.0 support is not built in yet to VS 2017. I wrote more more detail about this limitation here: http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/02/01/project-json-to-csproj-part2/ Read the section about VS vs dotnet.exe

Comment: Thanks for the comment. When I build on the command line I get the following error:

Comment: C:\Users\{user}\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.0-beta-25017-01\build\NETStandard.Library.targets(80,5): error MSB4062: The "HandlePackageFileConflicts" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\{user}\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.0-beta-25017-01\build\NETStandard.Tools.dll. Assembly with same name is already loaded Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [D:\x.csproj]

Comment: I'm thinking this is because I am referencing the netstandard.Library in project x but if I remove it I get compile time errors.

Comment: Well, like I said...these bits are very unstable. You can open bugs on https://github.com/dotnet/sdk and https://github.com/dotnet/standard.

Comment: Here are some more details on dogfooding: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/dogfooding.md

Comment: Thanks, following the dogfooding sorted it, I added the  <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.0-beta-xyz-00</RuntimeFrameworkVersion> within the console app to target the beta version of netstandard.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Core 2.0 SDK (final release) is available including tools for vs 2017 /2015.

You can [download](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core)  and it's integrated with vs 2017.3

Note that if you installed this version: [dotnet-sdk-2.0.0-win-gs-x64](http://microsoft.com/net/core), it didn't show in visual studio 2017.3,[ref](http://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/961)

For feature details read: [Announcing .NET Core 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/)

Also, [ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/08/14/announcing-asp-net-core-2-0/) is available

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core 2.0 is not on the [Download](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md) page and it is expected to be released in Q2 2017 [on the roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md).

You should use .NET Core 1.1 and target .NET Standard 1.6 for now.

And yes: you must download the SDK if you want to develop.

Answer (score 0):

if you have both Core and DotNet 4.X within the same solution, you may want to consider adding netcoreapp2.0 to your "<\TargetFramework>" tag.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 <PropertyGroup>
 <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```